# Virtual Host Proxy redirect error

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I'm running Apache on a couple of servers.  I'm trying to redirect 1 site from my main server onto another server on my internal network.  On my main server I've setup a .conf file master.conf with the following:

```
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
ServerName mysite.co.uk
ServerAlias www.mysite.co.uk
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.203:80
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.203:80
<Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I believe in order to get Proxies working correctly I also need a .conf file on my slave server with the same name so I have master.conf on my slave with the following:

```
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/master
```

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server error.  Can you advise

Comment: have you tried to use your setting in side one virtualhost?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question.  In both cases above the text is containted within `<VitrualHost *:80> </VirtualHost>` tags.

Comment: if your above test is contained within the virtualhost directive, why you don't include that in your question?

Comment: I do apologise.  I took it as given